# Remove borders on a violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to remove the black outline on my violin plot - I don't want an outline at all
Please help! The violin plot is grouped with a box plot.
Can't work out what code I should use

Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The "outline" of `geom_violin` is controlled by the `linewidth` parameter, just set it to zero in your `geom_violin`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price)) + geom_violin(linewidth = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Another potential option is to set the colour to "transparent", i.e.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = price)) +
  geom_violin(color = "transparent")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>